# simplexml_load_string get attributes

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

**The source XML is:**

```
<attributeGroup id="999" name="Information">
   <attribute id="123" name="Manufacturer">Apple</attribute>
   <attribute id="456" name="Model">iPhone</attribute>  
</attributeGroup>
```

**Code:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
print_r($xml);
```

**output:**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 999
            [name] => Information
        )

    [attribute] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apple
            [1] => iPhone
        )

)
```

How do I also get it to return the labels of `attribute id` and `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it like this using attributes property:

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$g = $x->attributeGroup;
foreach($g->xpath("//attribute") as $attr){
    var_dump((string)$attr->attributes()->id);
    var_dump((string)$attr->attributes()->name);
    var_dump((string)$attr); // for text value
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked, but how can I also get the text values in the same array? So it would show the id, name, and text value.

Answer (score 0):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/794817)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string=' <attributeGroup id="999" name="Information">
                <attribute id="123" name="Manufacturer">Apple</attribute>
                <attribute id="456" name="Model">iPhone</attribute>  
   </attributeGroup>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$result=array();
foreach($xml->xpath("//attribute") as $attr)
{
    $result[(string)$attr->attributes()->id]= (string) $attr->attributes()->name;
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [123] => Manufacturer
    [456] => Model
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So many over-complicated answers to something that is very clearly shown in the PHP manual here: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

You just need to do this:

```
$sx = simplexml_load_string($xml);
// $sx is the outer tag of your XML; in your example <attributeGroup>
// Access child tags with ->
foreach($sx->attribute as $attr){
    // Access attributes with ['...']
    var_dump((string)$attr['id']);
    // Access text and CDATA content with (string)
    var_dump((string)$attr);
}
```